# C++ can't write to file

Tags: c++, text-files, fstream

I'm struggling with this code for some time now. To simply put my question I want to read 2 Names from file1 and then write it to  the line of the file2. It's reads the name just fine but it doesn't write it to the file2.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
int rand1 = 0,line_num = 0;
string Meno,Dni;


fstream ZoznamMien ("C:/Programovanie/Generator_dot/Dotaznik.txt");
fstream VolneDni ("C:/Programovanie/Generator_dot/Dni.txt");

srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
rand1 = rand() % 16;

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    while (getline(ZoznamMien, Meno))
    {
        if (line_num == rand1)
        {
            getline(VolneDni, Dni);
            if (i == 0)
            {
                Dni = Dni + ' ' + Meno + ',';
            }
            else
            {
                Dni = Dni + ' ' + Meno;

            }
            cout << Dni << endl;
            cout << Meno << endl;
            break;
        }
        line_num++;
    }
        VolneDni << Dni;
}
}
```

Comment: Please, give us a fully working example of your code

Comment: How do your files look like? What's the content?

Comment: How do you make sure that if (line_num == rand1)  is true so that later write can be executed?

Comment: I suggest you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). When and where do you write to the stream `VolneDni`?

Comment: @NutCracker in the file named ZoznamMien i have 16 lines and in each line i have one name of my clasmates.And in the file named VolneDni i have 8 lines and in each line i have the date of appointment.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i already talked it through with my friend who is more experienced than me and he couldn't find the mistake i made.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i write to the file right after i put the 2 sttrings with the names together

Comment: Did you try to use a debugger to go through your code line by line and see what happens?

Comment: Yeah sure i did and everything there looks just fine

Answer (score 3):

What's the logic beyond this condition: `if (line_num == rand1)`.

It's based on random numbers, so file2 will only be written if this `rand1` only has a value of 0 in the first iteration, 1 in the second iteration or 2 at the third iteration.

Comment: i moved the writting right  after the if (line_num== rand1) statment and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @PeterKoszorus You forgot to close the file.

Comment: No i didn't forgot to close the file .

Comment: @PeterKoszorus What about `getline(VolneDni, Dni);` ? It reads from the file that's supposed to write to.

Comment: @PeterKoszorus Anyway, I'd like to suggest that you edit your question with your up-to-date code till now.

Comment: all right i will edit it and yes it reads from the file it supposed to write

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a look at the code where you create and write the new string to the file (with some added comments):

```
if (i == 0)
{
    // Create the new string
    Dni = Dni + ' ' + Meno + ',';

    // Don't write the new string to the file
}
else
{
    // Create the new string
    Dni = Dni + ' ' + Meno;

    // Write the new string to the file
    VolneDni << Dni;
}
```

You only write to the string in the `else` part, not when `i == 0`.

One solution is to do the writing *after* the `if`:

```
// Create the new string
if (i == 0)
{
    Dni = Dni + ' ' + Meno + ',';
}
else
{
    Dni = Dni + ' ' + Meno;
}

// Write the new string to the file
VolneDni << Dni;
```

Comment: I moved the VolneDni<<Dni right after the if condition like you told me and it still doesnt write anything to the file

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple changes. You should check if files are opened successfully or not. Random number should be regenerated each time. Also file should be read from start at each iteration.Write to ouput file before breaking loop.

Working code should be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std; 
int main()
{
int rand1 = 0,line_num = 0;
string Meno,Dni;



fstream VolneDni ("C:/Programovanie/Generator_dot/Dni.txt");


for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    rand1 = rand() % 16;
    fstream ZoznamMien ("C:/Programovanie/Generator_dot/Dotaznik.txt");
    if( !ZoznamMien.is_open() ) {
        cout<<" file did not open "<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    Dni="";
    while (getline(ZoznamMien, Meno))
    {
        if (line_num == rand1)
        {
            getline(VolneDni, Dni);
            if (i == 0)
            {
                Dni = Dni + ' ' + Meno + ',';
            }
            else
            {
                Dni = Dni + ' ' + Meno;

            }
            cout << Dni << endl;
            cout << Meno << endl;
            VolneDni << Dni;
            break;
        }
        line_num++;
    }

}
}
```